# Python array of tuples group by first, store second

Tags: python, list, dictionary, group-by

So I have an array of tuples something like this

```
query_results = [("foo", "bar"), ("foo", "qux"), ("baz", "foo")]
```

I would like to achieve something like:

```
{
    "foo": ["bar", "qux"],
    "baz": ["foo"]
}
```

So I have tried using this

```
from itertools import groupby

grouped_results = {}
for key, y in groupby(query_results, lambda x: x[0]):
    grouped_results[key] = [y[1] for u in list(y)]
```

The issue I have is although the number of keys are correct, the number of values in each array is dramatically lower than it should be. Can anyone explain why this happens and what I should be doing?

Comment: This: `[y[1] for u in list(y)]` should be `[u[1] for u in y]`

Comment: Also, note, `itertools.groupby` works like this: `[k for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')] --> A B C D A B`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You better use a `defaultdict` for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in query_results:
    result[k].append(v)
```

Which yields:

```
>>> result
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'baz': ['foo'], 'foo': ['bar', 'qux']})
```

If you wish to turn it into a *vanilla* dictionary again, you can - after the `for` loop - use:

```
result = dict(result)
```

this then results in:

```
>>> dict(result)
{'baz': ['foo'], 'foo': ['bar', 'qux']}
```

A `defaultdict` is constructed with a *factory*, here `list`. In case the key cannot be found in the dictionary, the factory is called (`list()` constructs a new empty list). The result is then associated with the key.

So for each key `k` that is not yet in the dictionary, we will construct a new list first. We then call `.append(v)` on that list to append values to it.

Comment: Why not use a simple dictionary?

Comment: @SamChats: because it is more elegant, and easy to change if one for instance wants to use sets insteads of lists. Your code constructs a lot of empty lists that are immediately omitted. Furthermore the list append `+` works in *O(n)*, making the algorithm *O(n^2)*.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was doubting whether my code would scale up. And, you mean `+` works in O(n) and `append` works in O(n^2)?

Comment: @SamChats: no, the amortized cost of `append(..)` is *O(1)*. So that makes it an *O(n)* algorithm (given lookup can be done in *O(1)*). Appending two lists, like `somelist + [foo]` is done in *O(n)*: it scales with the size of `somelist`, making the time complexity worse of the `.get(key, []) + [value]` solution.

Comment: @SamChats no! `+` is a linear operation, so if it is inside a loop you have O(n^2) overall. `.append` is *constant time*, so inside a loop, it is linear overall.

Answer (score 2):

Well why not use a simple `for` loop?

```
grouped_results = {}
for key, value in query_results:
    grouped_results.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

Output:

```
{'foo': ['bar', 'qux'], 'baz': ['foo']}
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! I've edited my code. But I haven't added `defaultdict` as it would make my answer redundant.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `defaultdict`?

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for pair in query_results:
    d[pair[0]].append(pair[1])
```

Comment: Awesome. But I think using `key, value` would be a better practice than using `pair` with `pair[0]` and `pair[1]`.